# Swift proper use of protocol extension

Tags: swift, protocols, protocol-extension

I'm trying to extract some of the code base for re use purpose. My approach is using `Protocol` and `Protocol` `Extension` instead of general `BaseClass`.

I have create the below a `protocol` and `protocol extension`

```
protocol MovieDisplay {

    var collectionView: UICollectionView! { get set }
    var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl! { get set }

}

extension MovieDisplay where Self: UIViewController {

    var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl {
        let rc = UIRefreshControl()
        rc.backgroundColor = .clear
        rc.tintColor = .lightGray
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            collectionView.refreshControl = rc
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
            collectionView.addSubview(rc)
        }
        return rc
    }

}
```

In my main class that adopt the protocol I declare like this (using default implementation of `refreshcontrol`)

```
class PopularMovieVC: UIViewController, MovieDisplay {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

}
```

The problem is function which involve `refreshcontrol` does not work. It works only when I explicitly declare `refreshcontrol` variable inside main class and convert extension into function and call it inside main class like below:

```
func setupRefreshControl() {
            refreshControl.backgroundColor = .clear
            refreshControl.tintColor = .lightGray
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                collectionView.refreshControl = refreshControl
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
                collectionView.addSubview(refreshControl)
            }
}
```

How to properly configure the `protocol` and `protocol extension` for default implementation?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because the computed property isn't called implicitly.

Adding this line in `viewDidLoad` should initialize the refresh control

```
_ = refreshControl
```

In this case I'd really prefer a base class

Comment: adding _ = refreshControl also not working.  Do you know any approach which does not involve base class?

Comment: If it doesn't work you are going to fight the framework. What's wrong with a base class?

Comment: Nothing wrong with a base class. I just dont want to end up with bloated base class in later state and want to try making few protocol and protocol extension which can be reuse separatedly

Answer (score 1):

Your protocol requires a gettable and settable `refreshControl` (that returns `UIRefreshControl!`), but your default implementation only provides a getter (and that getter returns a different type, `UIRefreshControl`). Your default implementation also returns a different `UIRefreshControl` every time it is accessed, and modifies `collectionView` every time it's accessed. None of this, I think, is what you mean.

As vadian notes, I think a base class is what you really want here, if you want to modify `collectionView.refreshControl` automatically. Conforming to a protocol should never cause implicit changes to other properties, and in most cases it can't. Imagine if `PopularMovieVC` were conformed to `MovieDisplay` in an extension in another module. That would lead to confusion at best.

Protocol conformance extends how a type can be used, such as adding new methods. It doesn't change anything about the type itself. If you want to change something about the type itself, you need something like inheritance or composition, not protocol conformance.

---

If you're doing a bit of this, I wouldn't do it with protocols this way. I'd just create extensions like this:

```
extension UIRefreshControl {
    static func makeStandard(attachedTo collectionView: UICollectionView) -> UIRefreshControl {
        let rc = UIRefreshControl()
        rc.backgroundColor = .clear
        rc.tintColor = .lightGray
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            collectionView.refreshControl = rc
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
            collectionView.addSubview(rc)
        }
        return rc
    }
}

extension UIActivityIndicatorView {
    static func makeStandard() -> UIActivityIndicatorView {
        return UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .gray)
    }
}
```

Then your view controller might look like:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    private var refreshController: UIRefreshControl!
    @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView.makeStandard()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        refreshController = .makeStandard(attachedTo: collectionView)
    }
}
```

No protocols needed, and this allows you to handle multiple collection views in the same view controller, or any other unusual situation. It also makes it clearer that calling this method will modify the collection view.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your clarification. So what the recommended approach? (in case no base class). My bellow solution which convert to default function in protocol extension and call it inside main class should be used?

Comment: Exactly. You can add `setupRefreshControl` as a extension on `MovieDisplay` and call it inside `viewDidLoad` or other convenient location. So it becomes a convenience method, rather than trying to modify the type's behavior.

Comment: Thanks incase of UIActivityIndicatorView which does not involve implicit changes to others properties. The approach still same? (declare variable in protocol, provide default setup in protocol extension, declare variable in main class, call the setup method?)

Comment: See comments above. I would drop the protocols. They're not necessary. Just use static functions if you want some kind of standard values for your app.